# How to put an vector array into an 1-d array by c++

Tags: c++

Hello~   I wanto to put vector into an 2-d array
First,I will create 1-d array named **user**

and I want to insert a vector to the 1-d array

for example: A 2-d array **user**(2X3),I want put a **vector** to user[0][1];

2-d array **user**

[ ]  [ ]      - - >point to a `vector<int> v(1,1);`

[ ]  [ ]

[ ]  [ ]

The link below is what I expect to

How should I do ??
thanks

https://www.dropbox.com/s/j166idfupez1kh1/vector.png?dl=0

Comment: really not clear what you are asking, although the most plain use of vector/array or even list solves the problem.

Comment: put all relevant information in the question, most people wont bother checking your dropbox link for it. Also, it makes the question useless as soon as the link becomes invalid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm interpreting this as you have a vector and you want to put the items in an array instead. This is one way to do it.

Suppose you have the vector `v` already full of items and you want to put it into an array.

Declare an array on the stack:

```
const auto sz = v.size();
TypeOfVector array[sz];
```

Then use `std::copy` to copy the contents of the vector into the array:

```
std::copy(std::begin(v), std::end(v), std::begin(array));
```

At least that's what I think you're asking!

Comment: `array[v.size()]` ... `v.size()` is only known at runtime. need to use operator new[]. Also, for a beginner I think a for loop with indexing is more clear to understand, even though std algos are more idiomatic.

Comment: Yes, I know that it should be a constant expression, was a bit too lazy to do that, I'll edit my answer.

Comment: FYI const auto there doesn't make a difference.

Comment: should it be `constexpr`? Actually nevermind, `size()` is probably not `constexpr` either.

Comment: exactly, it is not known at compile time. You would need something like: `TypeOfVector* array = new TypeOfVector[v.size()];` with a corresponding `delete array;` later. but that is ugly. If you know the array size at compile time, its better. OP hasn't given us any code, so we can only assume.